# internationalization i18n using next js pages router

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization, next.js13

[This is my folder structure how can i implement the dutch & english language translation for the whole website need help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVUHp.png)

I tried some ways like i18n localizely but that works for a single page etc but i want to implement on a whole website

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use Next-intl if the project using Next 13.x+
you can follow the document https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started. you can use translation whatever component is client or server side